# How to reduce the GPU consumption size while using Elmo Model?

Tags: deep-learning, tensorflow, nlp, python-3.x

I am performing an NLP task using `Elmo` model. Whenever I load the Elmo model, it occupies the 15 GB of my GPU memory. How can I reduce it ?

Below is my code

```
import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf
import tensorflow_hub as hub
tf.disable_eager_execution()
from tensorflow.compat.v1.keras import backend as K
sess = tf.Session()
K.set_session(sess)

elmo_model = hub.Module("https://tfhub.dev/google/elmo/2", trainable=True)
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
sess.run(tf.tables_initializer())


def ElmoEmbedding(x):
    return elmo_model(inputs={
                    "tokens": tf.squeeze(tf.cast(x, tf.string)),
                    "sequence_len": tf.constant(batch_size*[maxlen])
              },
              signature="tokens",
              as_dict=True)["elmo"]
```

And then I am passing the ElmoEmbedding in the Lambda layer as below

```
input_text = Input(shape=(maxlen,), dtype=tf.string)

embedding = Lambda(ElmoEmbedding, output_shape=(maxlen, 1024))(input_text)

x = Bidirectional(LSTM(units=512, return_sequences=True,
               recurrent_dropout=0.2, dropout=0.2))(embedding)

.....
```

**What do I need to change in the above code ?**

Answer (score 1):

I understand that you are doing only inference, so you shouldn't need your model to be trainable, and therefore you can set the parameter `trainable` to `False` when invoking `hub.Module`.

Comment: hey thanks for the reply....actually I was trying to make a custom NER model, thats why I kept `trainable=True`

Comment: Then I don't see how you could just reduce the amount of memory needed for the model.

Comment: Ohh okay :(  well thank you so much for replying